# Limit str_replace to act only once in a string

Tags: php

Let's suppose my ARRAY contains values:

```
  $marVans = Array(
        'SELECT SIZE' => '',
        "09 10 YRS" => "9-10 ANI", 
        "11 12 YRS" => "11-12 ANI", 
        "13 14 YRS" => "13-14 ANI", 
        "15 16 YRS" => "15-16 ANI",
        "08" => "XS",
        "10" => "S",
        "12" => "M",
        "14" => "L",
        "16" => "XL"
     );
```

When I do the `str_replace()` for the initial array, where I search these keys, like below, it replaces me also the 10,12,14..etc in the first occurences, so it returns me the final values as 9-S ANI, 11-M ANI

```
str_replace(array_keys($marVans), $marVans, $marimiIntregi);
```

Any ideas of how this can be fixed? I want it to replace individually, so this "09 10 YRS" => "9-10 ANI" and  this "10" => "S" work as desired.

Comment: Are you simply trying to get the values on the right hand side? e.g. `9-10 ANI`, `11-12 ANI` from this `$marsVans` array?

Comment: Yes but also to not replace the `10` in the `9-10 ANI` for example and act individually on its value and become `S` only when it is standalone

Comment: "work as desired"  And what exactly is desired?  You haven't actually said what you're trying to achieve here.  Given your example input array, what should the output be?

Comment: Provide with expected output

Comment: I want that the numeric values in the end of the array to not conflict and replace in the `9-10 ANI`, because right now it returns me `9-S ANI`

Comment: No Adrian, edit your question with a expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to move over to using [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) instead:

```
strtr($marimiIntregi, $marVans);
```

The translations done by `strtr` won't conflict with each other, and it takes the exact format of translation pairs that you've already used.

See https://eval.in/894736 for an example.

Comment: Hey, still got this issue in other strings, if I don't have them defined in the array, it replaces those numeric values in the string. Is it possible to search if the string is exactly the same as the defined values only? Like if it's `10` to not replace in those who are like `9-10 years` and not defined

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation of `str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) explains:

> If `search` and `replace` are arrays, then `str_replace()` takes a value from each array and uses them to search and replace on `subject`.

This means, in your case it first replaces `SELECT SIZE` with the empty string (`''`) then `09 10 YRS` with `9-10 ANI` and so on.

The solution to your problem is to change the order of the replacement pairs such as later search values are not substrings of previous replacements (i.e. put the last 5 entries first):

```
$marVans = Array(
    'SELECT SIZE' => '',
    "08" => "XS",
    "10" => "S",
    "12" => "M",
    "14" => "L",
    "16" => "XL"
    "09 10 YRS" => "9-10 ANI", 
    "11 12 YRS" => "11-12 ANI", 
    "13 14 YRS" => "13-14 ANI", 
    "15 16 YRS" => "15-16 ANI",
);
```

Answer (score -2):

can be done with preg_replace:

```
function str_replace_first($from, $to, $subject)
{
    $from = '/'.preg_quote($from, '/').'/';
    return preg_replace($from, $to, $subject, 1);
 }
str_replace_first('abc', '123', 'abcdef abcdef abcdef'); 
// outputs '123def abcdef abcdef'
```